# C3js chart lines hides after grunt build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, gruntjs, c3.js

I draw a chart line on an angularjs app with c3js. It shows normally. Just after I run grunt build then run the app on dist folder, but didn't show the line.

When I debug I found that the transition duration of d3js done for showing the graph cause the issue, when I remove the transition duration on the build version, it works. What cause this issue?

Comment: to use c3js with angularjs I recommend using [angular-chart](https://github.com/GraFiddle/angular-chart)

Comment: and are you sure `c3.css` is fully available/not overwritten etc. after `grunt build`?

Comment: The c3.css isn't overwritten and it is fully available. I'll try the angular-chart and tell you if it works.

Comment: I used angular-chart then build it and the line disapear again.

Comment: so I am pretty sure there's an issue with your styling - but I won't be able to help you unless you share your code.

Comment: I test a build from scratch with just an angular-chart then build it and it works. you're right it is an issue with styles or conflict in js after build. I can't post the whole project it's huge and confidential, and cannot post just a part of it because the issue can come from everything. So what would you recommand?

Comment: e.g. check in Chrome DeveloperTools were your opactiy = 0 value's origin is - you'll have to debug it, I can't help you any further

Comment: I've modify the second paragraph, please take a look on the new causes I found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, it was a conflict with Date.js, and we know that there is a conflict in transition of D3js and Date.js.

Also I was writing the date.js on my index, but comment it, and grunt build command ignore the comment and integer the script even if it is commented.

So the solution is to remove the commented link script of date.js